# How to set up to 2 digits after point

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL there is some datatypes for real numbers:
decimal(p,s)
numeric(p,s)
float
real

In decimal and numeric we can force 2 digits after the point.

Examples:

```
1.234 -> 1.23
1.000 -> 1.00
1.1 -> 1.10
```

I search for way to save floating number to DB, force up to 2 digits, and that the data will not adding zeros to fill the 2 digits:

Examples:

```
1.234->1.23
1.000-> 1
1.1 -> 1.1
```

Comment: so to confirm you want to have trailing 0's e.g. 1.00

Comment: First of all do not confuse storage with presentation. `1.00` vs `1.0` has no sense for data storage. If you want to store a rounded number you can use `ROUND(value, 2)` function in your `INSERT` or simply store it as is and round it for presentation: `SELECT ROUND(columnName, 2) FROM tableName`

Comment: What data type are these? float, varchar, nvarchar etc?

Comment: @Matt No, I dont want the zeros after the point. e.g if the number is 1.20 I want to save this as 1.2

Comment: @Adriano Repetti I insert 1.2 and 1.23 and 1.238 to the table. when I select this fields I get 1.20 and 1.23 and 1.24. I want to select this fields and get 1.2 and 1.23 and 1.24

Comment: You do  not **save** as 1.20 vs 1.2. You save binary representation of that number and it's presented with or without trailing zero

Comment: @OrK : you appear to misunderstand what is happening.  Numbers are stored in binary, not as strings or in decimal notation.  That `0` isn't an artefact of what is in the database, it's an artefact of how it is converted to a string for presentation.  `CAST(1.2 AS DECIMAL(8,2))` ***will*** coerce the value to the level of precision you want.  After that there is a completely separate question about how ***you*** are ***displaying*** the numbers.  Whatever your presentation layer is should deal with formatting, not the database.

Comment: OK, I am understand.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the`ROUND` function.

```
SELECT round(field,2)
FROM yourtable
```

INPUT

```
field
1.234
1.000
1.1
```

OUTPUT

```
1.23
1
1.1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f08ee/26/0

Comment: Thanks, In MSSQL it is work different. the round function padding with zeros 2 digits after the point.